# Keep scene size between different windows

Tags: resize, window, javafx-2

I use this to change between different windows in my JavaFX program:

```
Stage stage = (Stage) menuBar.getScene().getWindow();
Parent root;
try {
    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(window + ".fxml"));
Scene scene = new Scene(root);
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();
```

But if I have changed the size in the window, the new window is resized to the original size (1200x700), how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the overloaded constructor of `Scene` as:

```
Scene oldScene = menuBar.getScene();
Stage stage = (Stage) oldScene.getWindow();
Parent root;
try {
    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(window + ".fxml"));
Scene scene = new Scene(root, oldScene.getWidth(), oldScene.getHeight());
stage.setScene(scene);
```